# how to increase priority of ftdi driver in linux?

Tags: linux, driver, ftdi

I'm gathering a video stream form usb, by using FT2232H in fedora 26 and QT5.6  .

I'm using a thread only for read data from ftdi port and also, i changed that thread priority to real time.
I download driver from :

https://www.intra2net.com/en/developer/libftdi/index.php

My video stream is about  180 MBit/sec. 
I have a fifo in my FPGA (about the 36kbyte). As we know, the fifo of FT2232H is 4kbyte.

but my FIFO is full in some cases !!. then >>
but in my hardware i have loss data !!.

Then i guess that i can solve my problem with change the priority of FTDI driver, but i can't find any things.

1) how to change the FTDI driver priority?
2) how much FIFO i need before the FTDI in my hardware? (i have a core-i5 3G clock )

Comment: Why are you using USB Serial conversion now? Switching to the USB Video Class interface will alleviate such problems.

Comment: video class not supported in ft2232h. that's for ft60X in ftdi.

Comment: As you say, switching to FT60X or FT90X etc. is conceivable.

Comment: but i need to solve this problem with current board. :(